# Blurry Images on Iphones

Tags: adobe-photoshop, iphone

I have a design created via Photoshop using 72dpi.

Save image for web as PNG or JPEG doesn't matter.

The images really looks fuzzy on iphones only. Why is that?

Comment: Hi Jeremi, could you elaborate your question? What version of iPhone and iOS have you tested? Could you include some screenshots as an example? Also, take a look at http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions for an idea of screen sizes and resolutions on iPhones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't designed for the retina display of recent apple hardware. (I assume you are making images for a website) Generally speaking you need to supply images at twice the pixel width for the same amount of image space.
That means, if the image space in your HTML is 200px wide, you need to make the image 400px.

```
<img src="my400image.jpg" width="200">
```

There's a whole lot more to it than this with different ways to do the same thing (like using SVG's, potentially new img element and media queries) so you may want to read up some more.